# Help me identify this circular connector

Tags: identification, connector, circular

I'm trying to identify this connector so I can make an extension cable.  The connector has 12 pins, although only 4 of them are wired.  There is a logo which is about 1mm square, so I've drawn it.

[image: Size]

[image: Plug]

[image: Socket]

[image: Logo]

Comment: Is it used in audio equipment? I can find Nuemann SM2 or Tuchel connector references. (looks like long obsoleted)

Comment: ? https://www.slgu.com.ar/index.html

Comment: The logo is Binder connectors and this would be 12 pin panel mount "bulkhead" (male+female) connector. Possible a MIL spec connector (is the side colored in ugly moss green?). Let me see if I can find it...

Comment: Or are your pics actually of 2 different connectors?

Answer (score 2):

The logo is for Binder connectors. This is as close as I got:

Binder, part no: 09 0131 80 12

M16 IP67 Male panel mount connector, Contacts: 12, unshielded, solder, IP67, UL, front mounting

https://www.binder-connector.com/se-en/products/datasheet-09-0331-00-12.pdf

Might not be an exact match, but from here you could just ask Binder what part it is.